# How to remove text inside an element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, replace

I have a script that creates a list of items with a structure like this:

```
<li>
    <div>Some stuff</div>
    <a href="http://www.mysite.com/">New Item</a> 
    (1 vote)
</li>
```

I was wondering if there was a way to remove everything outside the `<div>` and `<a>` tags, in this case the (1 vote) string, with jQuery or regular javascript.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This has everything you want:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This should work.

```
$("li").contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType != 1; }).remove();
```

or by specifying text nodes explicitly

```
$("li").contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType == 3; }).remove();
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KNYde/).

Comment: Thanks! I  ended up using `$('ul li').contents().filter(function() {
                    return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
                  }).remove();`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li').html($(this).children())
```

You can try this, it should work. Clean and easy.

Comment: Interesting idea but html only takes a string. You can do `.empty().append(children)` but you would have to store the children before you do that

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').not('div,a').text('')
```

Try this, untested

**Edit**

```
$('li').contents().filter(function(){ return !(this.tagName == 'DIV' 
                                            || this.tagName == 'A');}).remove();
```

Comment: Nope, it does not work: http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/-247fd6d2e7667cb8732e56d5043f96db.php

Comment: No luck :( it does make sense though