# Remove text after input tag

Tags: jquery

I simply want to remove the text which is after input, any ideas ?

```
<label class="checkbox">
<input id="forms-element-0-0" name="checkbox[]" value="1" type="checkbox">
remove me
</label>
```

Comment: What about text before it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove text inside an element with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690445/how-to-remove-text-inside-an-element-with-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

I'd skip jQuery for this, if it's only the one `input`'s following-text, and use:

```
document.getElementById('forms-element-0-0').nextSibling.nodeValue = '';
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QPv7Z/).

To remove the `textNode` (rather than simply replace its text with an empty string):

```
var text = document.getElementById('forms-element-0-0').nextSibling;
text.parentNode.removeChild(text);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QPv7Z/2/).

If you have a collection of `label` elements to work through I'd suggest:

```
$('label').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).remove();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QPv7Z/1/).

References:

- DOM :

  - [`node.NextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nextSibling).
  - [`Node.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType).
  - [`Node.nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeValue).
  - [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode).
  - [`Node.removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild).
- jQuery methods:

  - [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Comment: why not just remove the node?

Comment: No particular reason, I just assumed it might be needed later.

Comment: @DavidThomas: Should be `nodeType` instead of `nodeValue` but otherwise the last one should work.